# :visible doesn't work after submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code http://jsfiddle.net/Z9qP5/1/

I want to fadeOut my form after the user submitted their email. There is the next problem.  I just can't catch the submit event, so what I want, if the success message appears, then the form should be hidden. I use `:visible` like this:

```
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit(function (e) {
    if($('#mce-success-response').is(':visible')){
        $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
    }
});
```

`#mce-success-response` **is the success dialog.**

I also tried:

```
if( $("#mce-success-response").css('display') == 'block') {
}
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: looks like the visibility of the response is set after the success handler is executed

Comment: The problem is the `mce-success-response` element is displayed after an ajax call which is again initialized on the form submit(the ajax submit)... so when your form submit handler is called the `mce-success-response` element is not yet displayed

Comment: I think you need to use ajax in this case

Comment: One possible solution in this case is to trigger an custom event on the form submit handler and use that custom event to do your stuff instead of using the submit handler

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to hide things on Submit event. But submit event is fired before work is sent.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I think the `submit` event is just a *one way*, you just submit, and you don't want to get response when you do like that way. maybe you can use ajax that can handle the result. actually, you just submit your form, then fade out your form I think.

Comment: I can use delay but invalid email is consider as submit, I have to catch the success.. I don't have full control as it's handle by MailChimp..

Comment: I see, you can use jQuery validation plugin, in that way, there is a validation handle, I think you use that handle to do you what you want do, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround, and not an effective solution.

But it works!

```
function checkSuccess() {
    if ($('#mce-success-response').is(':visible')) {
        $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
    }
} 
window.setInterval(checkSuccess, 100);
```

You could also use the code below to add a delay to the `hide`ing:

```
function checkSuccess() {
    function successAction(){
        $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();            
    }
    if ($('#mce-success-response').is(':visible')) {
        setTimeout(successAction, 2500);
    }
} 
window.setInterval(checkSuccess, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a custom event in this case(because as I explained in the comment the `success-respone` element is displayed in an ajax success handler).

So in your `mce_success_cb` method

```
if (resp.result == "success") {
    $('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').show();
    $('#mce-' + resp.result + '-response').html(resp.msg);
    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function () {
        this.reset();
    });

    $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").trigger('submitsuccess');
    // If the form has errors, display them, inline if possible, or appended to #mce-error-response
} else {
    //rest of your code
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submitsuccess', function (e) {
        $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the success response from AJAX after the submit? As per your code snippet, I am assuming that to be the case and that the success boz appears once your Ajax request is completed. Since its going to be for a short while, you can try the following piece of code.

```
function waitForIt(){
   if(!$('#mce-success-response').is(':visible')){
        setTimeout(waitForIt(),500);
    } else{
       $("#mc_embed_signup").hide(); 
}

$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit(function (e) {
        setTimeout(waitForIt(),500);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if its not the AJAX response that pops up the success message, you can try putting an interface between your form submit and the user action. Change your input type from `submit` to `button` or use a plain `image` as a button, i.e `<img>`. Use a `click()` instead of `submit()`, check if the container is visible, if yes, then hide the required container and `trigger` submit.

Hope it helps!